# How do you define the "depth" of a folder structure?

Tags: directory

This isn't a question directly related to any piece of software, but rather a question about terminology and definition of directory tree depth.

When I look at how `find . -maxdepth 0` works it seems that the only thing at depth 0 is `.`. And if you do `find . -maxdepth 1` it finds all directories and files that live at the directory `.`.

This seems counter-intuitive to me. I would think that any directory or file living at the root of a given path would be considered to be at the lowest depth of the tree, or depth = 0. But this doesn't appear to be in the case of the `find` command.

Take the following type of directory structure:

```
/
/fileA.txt
/home
/home/fileB.txt
/home/user
/home/user/fileC.txt
/home/user/morefiles
/home/user/morefiles/fileD.txt
```

With regards to directory/tree depth, how deep is each file relative to the root directory `/`? Is `fileA.txt` at depth 0 or 1? What about the `/home` directory? Is `fileC.txt` at depth 2 or 3? etc

I suppose the question can be simplified down to "Are files and folders located at `/` (such as `/fileA.txt`) at depth 0 or depth 1?" And is there an easy to understand explanation of why it's defined this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manpage of `find`, `maxdepth` is defined as follows.

```
-maxdepth 0  
 means only apply the tests and actions to the starting-points themselves.
```

So a file or folder which is in a starting directory is at depth 1. IN you particular case `fileA.txt` is at depth 1.
Your `/home/user/fileC.txt` is at depth 3, as `/home` is the first level, `/home/user` is the second level and finally `/home/user/fileC.txt` is at the third level of the hierarchy.

Concerning your question *Why it's definded this way?*, for me it just makes sense to have all files and folders at level 1 relative to the start  of your search and the starting point itself at level 0.
In IT you often start counting at 0 (zero), e.g. it is very common that the first element in an array is referenced by 0 (zero).
In `shell` the `$0` positional argument relates to calling shell or scriptname.